Potential malware from ybb-network.com
In my Screen Time on my Apple account, I'm seeing 24 hours a day over the last few weeks of accessing "https://ybb-network.com/". Screen Time confirms this is coming from my Mac Laptop.

I assume this is some kind of malware. Any suggestions on how to find the source of the malware and remove it?
Obviously I'd love to find the true source of the problem.
UPDATE: I downloaded the free trial of Malwarebytes, based on the recommendations here and after reading in several places that it's a trustworthy app.
It found a few "threats" in its scan:


I pressed the "quarantine" button on these, and I checked my browser extensions in Safari and Chrome, but I'm not seeing anything suspicious. Any other advice on how to remove them?

To solve this, I downloaded the free trial of Malwarebytes, based on the recommendations here and after reading in several places that it's a trustworthy app.
Malwarebytes found a few "threats" in its scan, related to Adware.Spigot. I quarantined and then deleted these 6 items. Since then, my laptop does not appear to be pinging ybb-network.com any more.
I then uninstalled Malwarebytes by going to its menu, "Help > Uninstall."

Let’s rule out the obvious cause first before we go down a malware path.
Tap on the name of the domain you wish to understand why and when a device contacted ybb-network.com by looking deeper into the App Privacy Report on any device. Apple lists dates, times,apps and other websites that call out to any similar site on my privacy report.


Great suggestion, @bmike. It turns out this is being accessed from my laptop, so I don't think I can use App Privacy Report on my laptop. Any other suggestions on how to track this down?

Excellent sleuthing @canary_in_the_data_mine since you have a Mac, I would do two things not obvious from the initial details. 1) grab a copy of malware bytes for Mac and scan for malware. 2) understand if your version of macOS could be updated and inspect all web browser plug in to try and correlate which browser is hitting that domain at which time stamp

thanks for the advice. See my update on what Malwarebytes found!

Sounds good. Be sure to put up an answer in the answer section the question should be a brief summary of the problem and not a blog post in the end.. thanks @canary_in_the_data_mine. The how to remove might properly be a totally new question as you now know why iOS reported that domain.

Upon detecting such a peak in strange trafic toward some specific web servers,
I always start by checking their trustworthyness with web servers dedicated to this kind of rating.
For example:
Scamvoid
Urlvoid
and…
not many more, because the other ones were already trying to sell me something or too much spying on my web browser environment ( which is a mine
field against cybercrime and crapware ).
If you want to investigate such a case on your own, run the following command:
netstat | egrep 'tcp[46]|Active Internet|Proto '

and insert the output within your OQ.
